# Is this generalization of Fredholm alternative true?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces. Let $\mathcal L(E, F)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$, and $\mathcal K(E, F)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. For a linear map $T$, we denote by $R(T)$ its range and by $N(T)$ its kernel. We have *Theorem 6.6* in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> **Fredholm alternative** Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map and $T \in \mathcal K(E, E)$. Then
>
> (a) $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$,
>
> (b) $R(I-T)$ is closed, and more precisely $R(I-T) = N(I-T^*)^\perp$,
>
> (c) $N(I-T) = \{0\} \iff R(I-T) = E$,
>
> (d) $\dim N(I-T)=\dim N(I-T^*)$.

With exactly the same proof as the one of *Fredholm alternative*, I have showed that

> **S1** Let $E_0$ be a closed subspace of $E$. Let $I:E_0 \to E$ be the identity map and $T \in \mathcal K(E_0, E)$. Then
>
> (a) $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$,
>
> (b) $R(I-T)$ is closed.

To be honest, I'm not sure whether my [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722628/brezis-exercise-6-9-4-is-there-a-shorter-proof-that-ris-is-closed) of **S1** is correct or not. There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize.

> **S2** Let $E_0$ be a closed subspace of $E$. Let $I:E_0 \to E$ be the identity map and $T \in \mathcal K(E_0, E)$. Then
>
> (a) $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$,
>
> (b) $R(I-T)$ is closed, and more precisely $R(I-T) = N((I-T)^*)^\perp$.
>
> (c) $N(I-T) = \{0\} \iff R(I-T) = E$,
>
> (d) $\dim N(I-T)=\dim N((I-T)^*)$.

My questions are as follows:

> Among conclusions (a), (b), (c), (d) of **S2**, which ones remain true? Can we prove those valid ones by Fredholm alternative?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Did you tried some simple examples in the finite-dimensional situation? Then, $I - T$ can be identified with an arbitrary matrix in $\mathbb R^{n \times m}$ with $n > m$.

Comment: S2 b,c are false: if $T=0$ then $R(I-T)=E_0 \ne E$.

Comment: @daw I can see that S2(c) is false. Could you explain why S2(b) is false?

Comment: I thought that $N((I-T^*))^\perp$ would be $E$ so different from $R(I-T)$, but this is wrong.