# Brezis' exercise 6.10.2: prove that $N(I-T) = \{0\} \iff R(I-T) = E$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, alternative-proof, compact-operators

Let $E,F$ be real Banach spaces. Let $\mathcal L(E, F)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$, and $\mathcal K(E, F)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $\mathcal L(E) := \mathcal L(E, E)$ and $\mathcal K(E) :=\mathcal K(E, E)$. For a linear map $T$, we denote by $R(T)$ its range and by $N(T)$ its kernel.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $Q(t) = \sum_{k=1}^p a_k t^k$ be a polynomial such that $Q(1) \neq 0$. Let $T \in \mathcal L(E)$ such that $Q(T) \in \mathcal K(E)$. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map.
>
> 1. Prove that $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$, and that $R(I-T)$ is closed. More generally, prove that $(I-T) (E_0)$ is closed for every closed subspace $E_0$ of $E$.
>    [**Hint:** Write $Q(1) - Q(t)=\widetilde Q (t) (1-t)$ for some polynomial $\widetilde Q$ and apply *Exercise 6.9*.
> 2. Prove that $N(I-T) = \{0\} \iff R(I-T) = E$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (2). Could you please have a check on it? Is there a shorter proof by [Fredholm alternative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722636/is-this-generalization-of-fredholm-alternative-true)?

---

Because $Q(1) \neq 0$, there is a real number $\alpha \neq 0$ such that $Q(I) = \alpha I$. There is a polynomial $\widetilde Q$ such that $Q(t)-Q(1) =\widetilde Q (1-t)$ for $t \in \mathbb R$, [so](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724178/is-it-true-that-qt-circ-rt-rt-circ-qt-for-all-q-r-in-mathbb-rx)
$$
\begin{align}
Q(T) &= Q(I) + \widetilde Q (I-T) \\
&= \alpha I + \widetilde Q (I-T).
\end{align}
$$

- $\implies$

Assume that $N(I-T) = \{0\}$. Let
$$
E_{n} := (I-T)^n (E)
\quad \forall n \ge 1
$$

By (1), $E_n$ is closed for $n \ge 1$. Assume the contrary that $E_1 \subsetneq E$. Because $I-T$ is injective, we have $E_{n+1} \subsetneq E_n$ for $n \ge 1$. By Riesz's lemma, there is a sequence $(u_n)$ such that $u_n \in E_n, |u_n|_E=1$ and $d(u_{n}, E_{n+1}) := \inf_{v \in E_{n+1}} |u_n-v|_E \ge 1/2$ for $n \ge 1$. For $m, n \ge 1$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha} (u_n-u_m) &= u_n-u_m - \frac{\widetilde Q (I-T)}{\alpha} u_n + \frac{\widetilde Q (I-T)}{\alpha} u_m.
\end{align*}
$$

Notice that $\widetilde Q (0)=0$, so $-\frac{\widetilde Q (I-T)}{\alpha} u_n \in E_{n+1}$ and $\frac{\widetilde Q (I-T)}{\alpha} u_m \in E_{m+1}$. For $m >n \ge 1$, we have
$$
E_{m+1} \subseteq E_m \subseteq E_{n+1} \subset E_n,
$$
and thus
$$
-u_m - \frac{\widetilde Q (I-T)}{\alpha} u_n + \frac{\widetilde Q (I-T)}{\alpha} u_m \in E_{n+1}.
$$

Then
$$
\left |\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha} (u_n-u_m) \right | \ge d(u_n, E_{n+1}) \ge \frac{1}{2}.
$$

So $(\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha} u_n)_n$ does not have any convergent sequence. This contradicts the fact that $Q(T)$ is compact. Hence $E_1 = E$.

- $\impliedby$

Assume that $R(I-T)=E$. Then $I-T$ is surjective. By *Corollary 2.18* in the same book, $N((I-T)^*)=N(I-T^*)=\{0\}$. We have $Q(T^*) =Q(T)^*$ is compact by Schauder's theorem. Then we apply direction "$\implies$" on $T^*$ and get $R((I-T)^*) = R(I-T^*) = E^*$, i.e., $(I-T)^*$ is surjective. By *Corollary 2.18* again, $N(I-T) = \{0\}$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks OK. In particular it makes sense that much of the "work" would be in one direction ($I-T$ injective implies $I-T$ surjective), with the rest being deducible from that via general facts about adjoints and nullspaces. Re potential simplification, the result is already nontrivial if $T$ is compact (i.e. the case $Q(t) = t$), where it (and/or Schauder's theorem) is sometimes used to *prove* the Fredholm alternative. And here the point is that $T$ may *not* be compact (the usual hypothesis of the alternative). So while there might be shorter proofs, I'd bet they rest on similar ideas.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you so much for your verification!