# Brezis' exercise 6.10.2: how does the author obtain $\left\|Q(T) u_n-Q(T) u_m\right\| \geq|Q(1)| / 2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Let $E,F$ be real Banach spaces. Let $\mathcal L(E, F)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$, and $\mathcal K(E, F)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $\mathcal L(E) := \mathcal L(E, E)$ and $\mathcal K(E) :=\mathcal K(E, E)$. For a linear map $T$, we denote by $R(T)$ its range and by $N(T)$ its kernel.

There is an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $Q(t) = \sum_{k=1}^p a_k t^k$ be a polynomial such that $Q(1) \neq 0$. Let $T \in \mathcal L(E)$ such that $Q(T) \in \mathcal K(E)$. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map.
>
> 1. Prove that $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$, and that $R(I-T)$ is closed. More generally, prove that $(I-T) (E_0)$ is closed for every closed subspace $E_0$ of $E$.
>    [**Hint:** Write $Q(1) - Q(t)=\widetilde Q (t) (1-t)$ for some polynomial $\widetilde Q$ and apply *Exercise 6.9*.
> 2. Prove that $N(I-T) = \{0\} \iff R(I-T) = E$.

The solution of (2) by the author is

> Proof of the implication $N(I-T)=\{0\} \Rightarrow R(I-T)=E$. Suppose by contradiction that $R(I-T)=E_1 \neq E$. Set $E_n=(I-T)^n E$. Then $\left(E_n\right)$ is a decreasing sequence of closed subspaces. Choose $u_n \in E_n$ such that $\left\|u_n\right\|=1$ and $\operatorname{dist}\left(u_n, E_{n+1}\right) \geq 1 / 2$. Write
> $$
> \begin{align}
> &Q(T) u_n-Q(T) u_m \\
> ={} &Q(T) u_n-Q(1) u_n+Q(1) u_n-Q(1) u_m+Q(1) u_m-Q(T) u_m \tag{1}
> \end{align}
> $$
> Thus, for $m>n$, we have
> $$
> \left\|Q(T) u_n-Q(T) u_m\right\| \geq|Q(1)| / 2, \tag{2}
> $$
> and this is impossible.
> For the converse, follow the argument described in the proof of *Theorem 6.6*.

Could you explain how the author goes from (1) to (2)? Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing the polynomial $\tilde{Q}$ with $Q(1) - Q(t) = \tilde{Q}(t) (1 - t)$ (as in point "1."), for any $n$ we have
\begin{align*}
Q(T) u_n - Q(1) u_n & = -\tilde{Q}(T) (I - T) u_n & \text{because $Q(t) - Q(1) = -\tilde{Q}(t) (1-t)$} \\
& \in -\tilde{Q}(T) E_{n+1} & \text{because $u_n \in E_n$ and $(I-T) E_n =: E_{n+1}$} \\
& \subseteq E_{n+1} & \text{because $-\tilde{Q}(T)$ commutes with $I-T$.}
\end{align*}
And hence for any $m$ we also have $(Q(1) - Q(T)) u_m \in E_{m+1}$, and if $m  > n$ we can deduce $E_{m+1} \subseteq E_{n+1}$ and hence $(Q(1) - Q(T)) u_m \in E_{n+1}$.

Similarly if $m > n$ then $u_m \in E_m \subseteq E_{n+1}$.

To summarize: if $m > n$ then the expression labeled (1) has the form $a_{n,m} + Q(1) u_n$, where $a_{n,m} \in E_{n+1}$.  Now we use how $u_n$ is chosen.  Can you finish?

Comment: In fact, $-\tilde{Q}(T)$ [commutes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724178/is-it-true-that-qt-circ-rt-rt-circ-qt-for-all-q-r-in-mathbb-rx) with any polynomial function of $T$, so I could not see how $-\tilde{Q}(T)$ commuting with $I-T$ implies $-\tilde{Q}(T) E_{n+1} \subset E_{n+1}$. Could you elaborate on this point?

Comment: If $A, B \in \mathcal{L}(E)$ and $AB=BA$, then for any $k$ one has $AB^k = B^k A$ also, so that $A B^k E = B^k A E \subseteq B^k E$ .  Taking $A = -\tilde{Q}(T)$ and $B = I - T$ and $k = n+1$ here we have $A E_{n+1} \subseteq E_{n+1}$.  (As you point out, here $-\tilde{Q}(T)$ commutes with any polynomial in $T$.  My remark took the above form, which is symbolically different but equivalent, because it is the powers of $I-T$ that are used to define the spaces $E_n$)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I got it. I have an alternative proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724857/brezis-exercise-6-10-2-prove-that-ni-t-0-iff-ri-t-e). If you don't mind, please have a check on it.