# Brezis' exercise 6.10.1: how to prove that $R(I-T)$ is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, compact-operators

Let $E,F$ be real Banach spaces. Let $\mathcal L(E, F)$ be the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ to $F$, and $\mathcal K(E, F)$ its subspace consisting of compact operators. Let $\mathcal L(E) := \mathcal L(E, E)$ and $\mathcal K(E) :=\mathcal K(E, E)$. For a linear map $T$, we denote by $R(T)$ its range and by $N(T)$ its kernel.

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $Q(t) = \sum_{k=1}^p a_k t^k$ be a polynomial such that $Q(1) \neq 0$. Let $T \in \mathcal L(E)$ such that $Q(T) \in \mathcal K(E)$. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map.
>
> 1. Prove that $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$, and that $R(I-T)$ is closed. More generally, prove that $(I-T) (E_0)$ is closed for every closed subspace $E_0$ of $E$.
>    [**Hint:** Write $Q(1) - Q(t)=\widetilde Q (t) (1-t)$ for some polynomial $\widetilde Q$ and apply *Exercise 6.9*.

The mentioned [Exercise 6.9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4722628/brezis-exercise-6-9-4-is-there-a-shorter-proof-that-ris-is-closed) is as follows, i.e.,

> Let $T \in \mathcal L(E, F)$.
>
> 1. Prove that the following properties are equivalent:
>
> - (A) $\dim N(T) < \infty$ and $R(T)$ is closed.
> - (B) There exist a constant $C>0$ and a finite-rank operator $P \in \mathcal L(E, E)$ such that $P=P^2$ and $|u|_E \le C (|Tu|_F + |Pu|_E)$ for all $u \in E$.
> - (C) There exist a Banach space $G$, an operator $Q \in \mathcal K(E, G)$, and a constant $C>0$ such that $|u|_E \le C (|Tu|_F + |Qu|_G)$ for all $u \in E$.
>
> 2. Assume that $T$ satisfies (A). Prove that $(T+S)$ also satisfies (A) for every $S \in \mathcal K(E, F)$.
> 3. Proce that the set of all operators $T \in \mathcal L(E, F)$ satisfying (A) is open in $\mathcal L(E, F)$.
> 4. Let $F_0$ be a closed linear subspace of $F$ and let $S \in \mathcal K(F_0, F)$. Prove that $R(I+S)$ is closed. Here $I$ is the identity map.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$. Could you have a check on it? Could you elaborate on how to prove that $R(I-T)$ is closed?

---

Because $Q(1) \neq 0$, there is a nonzero real number $\alpha$ such that $Q(I) = \alpha I$. We have
$$
N(I-T) \subset N(Q(I)-Q(T)) = N(\alpha I-Q(T)) = N \left (I-\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha} \right).
$$

Clearly, $I$ satisfies property (A) in *Exercise 6.9.1* and $-\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha}$ is a compact operator. By *Exercise 6.9.4*, $I-\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha}$ also satisfies property (A) and thus $\dim N \left (I-\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha} \right) < \infty$. It follows from $N(I-T) \subset N \left (I-\frac{Q(T)}{\alpha} \right)$ that  $\dim N(I-T) < \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the proof that $R(I-T)$ is closed as below.

---

There is a nonzero real number $\alpha$ such that $I= \alpha Q(I)$. Because $E_0$ is a closed subspace of the Banach space $E$, it is itself a Banach space. For $u \in E_0$,
$$
\begin{align*}
|u|_{E} &=|I u|_{E} \\
&= |\alpha Q(I) u|_{E} \\
&= |\alpha (Q(T) + \widetilde Q (T) (I-T)) u|_{E} \\
&\le |\alpha Q(T) u|_E + \| \alpha \widetilde Q (T)\| \cdot | (I-T) u|_{E} \\
&= \| \alpha \widetilde Q (T)\| \left  ( \left | \frac{\alpha}{\| \alpha \widetilde Q (T)\|} Q(T) u \right |_E + | (I-T) u|_{E}  \right )\\
\end{align*}
$$

We have $Q(T)$ is a compact operator, so is $\frac{\alpha}{\| \alpha \widetilde Q (T)\|} Q(T)$. The claim then follows from the equivalence in *Exercise 6.9.1*.